# Request doesn't go through the middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express, https, webhooks, twitch-api

I am integrating a Twitch API for subs, and having issue with getting the webhook callback response to the middleware function that it should check the header and verify the signature.

I am receive the right response! however, it stops right there!
I check the order of the routes, and I am not sure what I am missing

I am following https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/eventsub

```
app.post('/createWebhook/:broadcasterId', (req, res) => {
  const createWebHookParams = {
    host: "api.twitch.tv",
    path: "helix/eventsub/subscriptions",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Client-ID": clientId,
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + authToken
    }
  }

  const createWebHookBody = {
    "type": "channel.follow",
    "version": "1",
    "condition": {
      "broadcaster_user_id": req.params.broadcasterId
    },
    "transport": {
      "method": "webhook",
      "callback": "ngrokURL/notification",
      "secret": webhookSecret // 
    }
  }

  let responseData = ""
  const webhookReq = https.request(createWebHookParams, (result) => {
    result.setEncoding('utf8')
    result.on('data', (d) => {
        responseData = responseData + d
      })
      .on('end', (result) => {
        const responseBody = JSON.parse(responseData) // json
        console.log(responseBody)
        res.send(responseBody)
      })
  })
  webhookReq.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log("Error")
  })

  webhookReq.write(JSON.stringify(createWebHookBody))
  webhookReq.end()

});

// middlewsre ---> // not triggered!!!

app.use(express.json({
  verify: verifyTwitchSignature
}));

// making post to receeive the notification.

app.post('/notification', (req, res) => {
  console.log("incoming notificatin", req.body)
  
  res.status(200).end();
})


// the middleware verifing the signature
const crypto = require("crypto");

const twitchSigningSecret = process.env.SECRET;

const verifyTwitchSignature = (req, res, buf, encoding)=>{
const messageId = req.header("Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Id");
const timeStamp = req.header("Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Timestamp")
const messageSignature = req.header("Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Signature")

console.log(`Message ${messageId} Signature: `,messageSignature)


if (!twitchSigningSecret){
  console.log(`Twitch signing secret is empty`);
  throw new Error ("Twitch signing secret is empty.");

}


const computedSignature = "sha256=" + crypto.createHmac("sha256", twitchSigningSecret).update(messageId + timeStamp + buf).digist("hex");
console.log(`Message ${messageId} Computed Signature: `, computedSignature)

if (messageSignature !== computedSignature) {
  throw new Error("Invalid Signature.");
}else {
  
  console.log("Verification Successful");
}

}

module.exports = verifyTwitchSignature
```

Comment: The `app.use()` for the middleware needs to be done before the route handler.

Comment: Hi cbr! I had it on the top before all the routes but still not working, I specifically had it on the top of the route that needs to be check after!

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your `verifyTwitchSignature` function you need to pass `next` as one of the parameters and in the else-statement when it passes call `next();`.

That is my observation.

If you are working with middleware you always have to pass `next` together with `req` and `res`. `next` is what calls the next middleware or function in the queue.

Comment: Hi Johan, Thank you! the issue the request never go through the middleware at first place before move the next function! I believe the issue is calling the callback function from the webhook to get the response and then the middleware will run , which I am not seeing!